# how to customize QLPreviewController's navBar and toolbar tintColor

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

```
QLPreviewController * preview = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
preview.dataSource = self;
preview.currentPreviewItemIndex = sender.tag;
preview.editing= YES; 
[self presentModalViewController:preview animated:YES];
[preview release];
```

These two lines does not work for me. so be careful before writing these lines.

```
[preview.tabBarController.tabBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[preview navigationController].navigationBar setTintColor: [UIColor blackColor]];
```

[image: Problem Screenshot here]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since iOS5 you can theme controls based on instance, globally or when contained by specific container classes. Since iOS6 the former method of subclassing QLPreviewController to set the tintColor of the UINavigationBar stopped working.

Consider one of the following as an example of a workaround that is compatible with iOS5 and iOS6:

Any UINavigationBar contained within a QLPreviewController:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[QLPreviewController class], nil]
        setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

or globally set the tintColor of all UINavigationBar instances within your app with:

```
 [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

This same strategy works with the UITabBarController.

Answer (score 2):

set style of `UINavigationController` with this line..

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
```

and for change the color of TabBar just Add the below code in `viewWillAppear` of your class

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 48);
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[v setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.1 green:0.2 blue:0.6 alpha:0.8]];
[v setAlpha:0.5];
[[self.tabBarController tabBar] insertSubview:v atIndex:0];
[v release];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the tintColor of the navigationBar you can push your QLPreviewController instead present it modally:

```
//i assume that you already have a navigationController
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:previewer animated:YES];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

For the bottom bar i think that is a UIToolbar not a UITabBar, probably you cant change the color (i dont know), but surely you can't call `preview.tabBarController.tabBar`.

Comment: Very useful for iOS7 Tinting!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution , though it is not the correct way but it works:

Make subclass of `QLPreviewController`

MyQLPreviewController.h

```
@interface MyQLPreviewController : QLPreviewController

@end
```

and in .m of that new subclass, copy the following code

```
@implementation MyQLPreviewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    UIToolbar *toolbar = [self getToolBarFromView:self.view]; //NOTE: Not the correct apperoach! could not think better solution, as iOS does not allow to access the toolbar properties in QLPreviewController

    toolbar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];

}

- (UIToolbar *)getToolBarFromView:(UIView *)view
{
    for (UIView *subView in view.subviews)
    {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIToolbar class]])
        {
            return (UIToolbar *)subView;
        }
        else
        {
            UIToolbar *toolBar = [self getToolBarFromView:subView];

            if (toolBar)
            {
                return toolBar;
            }
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```